# Dynamically Add InfoWindow

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-flex-viewer, flex

I am developing a WebApp with Flex ArcGIS and I am trying to display an info window when I roll over a graphic that has been added to the graphics layer. I add a graphics layer when the widget loads and add the required listener for mouse over events, this works because when I try to show an Alert message on mouse over it works but trying to show an info window does nothing. This is the callback I used for mouseOver events

```
private function onMouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
             var gr:Graphic = Graphic(event.target);

             map.infoWindow.label = "Info";
             map.infoWindow.closeButtonVisible = true;
             map.infoWindow.show(map.toMapFromStage(event.stageX, event.stageY));
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

the service should be featurelayer. Then the features can be loaded to clients. Whenever mouseover envent triggered the attributes of the feature can be drawn without any http reqeust. 
 The sampe is as :
[esri flex samples link](https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/sample-code/infowindow-on-mouseover.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually used that method without a feature layer. Not sure if this is bad practice but I added the graphic details and added a listener as each feature was loaded to a graphics layer on the map. Then added the mouseover callback with info window.